# How many coins are expected to be used to raise the weapon from level $1$ to $9$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am solving a question about the expected value (I guess), but I have no idea how to approach it.

> Suppose I have a weapon, and it requires $1$ coin to raise the level by $1$.
> The probability of success is $50\%$ and failure is $50\%$.
> From level $5$, when it fails to level up, the level of the weapon will be reduced $1$. So, how many coins are expected to be used to raise the weapon from level $1$ to $9$?

I've tried to use R.V. to calculate the expected values before level $4$, which equal to $4 \times 0.5 = 2$, and I don't think that is correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You could use a Markov chain

Comment: If $E_n$ is the expected number of coins still needed when the weapon is level $n$, we have equations like $E_2 = 1 + \frac{1}{2}E_2 + \frac{1}{2}E_3$, $E_7 = 1 + \frac{1}{2}E_6 + \frac{1}{2}E_8$, and $E_9=0$. Can you see why, and write the rest? They're a bit tedious to solve, but not too bad working from one end to the other.